# Python audio streaming between two computers

Tags: python, audio, streaming, recording

I want to create a "Skype" like program that records audio from one computers and streams it live to another (just like a voice conversation) yet i can't find the right way to do it

(I also don't want any saved audio files, i want it to stream the audio without saving a file to the computer).

Any ideas about which module is right for this task and how should i do it?

Comment: `from nsa.prism import audio`

Comment: is [this](http://www.ugw.name/?page_id=157) the type of thing you're looking for?

Comment: What platform are you using? This requires audio handling and that tends to be platform specific.